# pyqgis - post-processing of layer output of QgsProcessingAlgorithm

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

While extending a plugin with a Processing Provider and a set of algorithms I mostly followed the defaults of `Plugin Builder 3`. So, the basic code is smth along the lines of

```
class ORSisochronesAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, configuration, p_str=None, Any=None, *args, **kwargs):

        # add all input parameters

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                'OUTPUT',
                'Output layer'
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT,
                context, source.fields(), source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs())

        features = source.getFeatures()

        for feature in features:
            new_feature = QgsFeature()

            # Some API calls and processing to populate new feature

            sink.addFeature(new_feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

So, the output layer is automatically handled and added to the map. Very nice!

But now: **How do I post-process that output layer** within the Processing Algorithm? Sounds weird maybe, but here are 2 scenarios:

- Depending on the value of a Boolean input parameter, I'd like to be able to calculate geometric differences of the output features. For this to work, the layer has to be built first. And then handled in some sort of post-processing.
- Also, I'd like to be able to customize the style of the output layer.

There is the `postProcessAlgorithm()` method for `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`, but I'm not so sure how to work with this.. It doesn't seem to take `parameters` as input, no idea how to access the output layer.

Being able to do this would make the plugin so much more user-friendly.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.. Using `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()` lets one access layers from the provided context and one can use that in the class's `postProcessAlgorithm()`. I'll post an answer if I have entirely succeeded. At least styling the layer already works:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to be more elaborate than the comment.

Basically, the `postProcessAlgorithm()` does what it says. It also returns a value map, including the `OUTPUT`. However, you need to look up the layer in the algorithm's context with `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()`. For that to work, you have to save a reference to the original output layer from `processAlgorithm()`:

```python
class ORSisochronesAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    dest_id = None  # Save a reference to the output layer id

    def initAlgorithm(self, configuration, p_str=None, Any=None, *args, **kwargs):

        # add all input parameters

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                'OUTPUT',
                'Output layer'
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        (sink, self.dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT,
                context, source.fields(), source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs())

        features = source.getFeatures()

        for feature in features:
            new_feature = QgsFeature()

            # Some API calls and processing to populate new feature

            sink.addFeature(new_feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}

    def postProcessAlgorithm(self, context, feedback):

        processed_layer = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(self.dest_id, context)

        # Do smth with the layer, e.g. style it

        return {self.OUT: self.dest_id}
```

Comment: I think it should be return {self.OUPUT: self.dest_id}